Best practice to use google map API key in flutter app
I am building an app where users will utilize Google Maps to locate nearby services.
I am interested in using the Google Maps widget in the Flutter app. I found information on "https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter#3" that mentions I need to enter the Android Map API Key in an XML file.
I am concerned about the security of adding my API key there. Will this API key be exposed in my app when I build and distribute the Android app to the app store?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
